# Are these devices cable quick-disconnects or adjusters?

Tags: cable

Are the devices in the photo cable quick-disconnects or adjusters?

[image: cable devices]

Comment: They are inline adjusters. IMHO they are unnecessary if your derailleurs already allow for adjustment. The inline adjusters just make cable installation more difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are adjusters for gear cables. They are mainly used for adjusting indexing.